Is there an explicit example of the bias-variance tradeoff?
This week I was trying to understand VC-theory and how it relates to this tradeoff.
All the plots I've seen so far seem to be empirical results: Someone made a bunch of simulations, estimated the quantities, and plotted them to give a picture similar to this

Do we have any toy model examples where you can calculate something like $\inf \text{Variance}+\text{bias}^2 > f$, for some function $f$ that does have this shape?
